# build c++ project using Make from two source directories in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have a **c++** project in **Linux** in which source files are in 2 directories as shown below. Currently, the **Makefile** only compiles the files in the **source/** directory, but **not** those in **"/"** directory. I've tried many hacks to no avail. How do you instruct **Makefile** to compile the source files in **"/"** directory after compiling those in **source/**, and put them in the **obj/** directory ?
I've tried many things to no avail...

A savvy hand is welcome !!

> **/**
> Makefile
> file1.cpp
> file2.cpp ...
>
> **source/**
> file30.cpp  file31.cpp  ...
>
> **obj/**
> file30.o  file31.o  ...

```
CC = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall
LDFLAGS = -pthread

APPNAME = trading_app
EXT = .cpp
SRCDIR = source
OBJDIR = obj

SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*$(EXT))
OBJ = $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) 
DEP = $(OBJ:$(OBJDIR)/%.o=%.d)

RM = rm
DELOBJ = $(OBJ)

all: $(APPNAME)

$(APPNAME): $(OBJ)
    @echo "building the executable..."
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
    @$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) $< -MM -MT $(@:%.d=$(OBJDIR)/%.o) >$@
 
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
    $(info $$OBJ is [${OBJ}])   
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<
```

Comment: You might also use the [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) tool to debug your `Makefile`, but you need to **read documentation** before.

Comment: Basile, yes I did. In fact I downloaded the GNU Make manual and I've read the first 5 chapters. This documentation is really good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you search only for files in the `SRCDIR` directory:

```
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*$(EXT))
```

but not for files in the current directory.  So of course make won't try to compile source files in the current directory.  If you want to build files in the current directory you need to add them to `SRC`.

Then you write a rule telling make how to compile files in the `SRCDIR` subdirectory and put them into the `OBJDIR` subdirectory:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%$(EXT)
```

but you don't have a rule telling make how to compile files in the current directory and put them into the `OBJDIR` subdirectory.  If you want make to know how to do that you have to give it a rule in the makefile that will do it.

Comment: Hi MadScientist, I had already tried it by adding the current directory like:

Comment: SRC = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*$(EXT)) $(wildcard *$(EXT))

Comment: _it didn't work_ is not a problem description we can help with.  In any event, I reported that there were TWO issues with your makefile; adding the source files to `SRC` is one, but you have to fix both to make things work.